# Fill missing values using last or previous observation R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following table:

```
ID Name Country
1  A    Nor
2  B    Nor
3  C    Nor
4  D    Nor
```

and I have another table:

```
ID Name Country
1  A    
2       Bel
3       Bel
4       Bel
```

the result I want to get is:

```
ID Name Country
1  A    Nor
2  B    Bel
3  C    Bel
4  D    Bel
```

Basically i would like to create a third table which will take as a priority the second table but will fill the missing fields with the second table based on ID. Any help on how to do this in base R will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the logical vector representing the locations of the `NA` values using `is.na(df2)`.

You can then set the `NA` elements of `df2` to be the corresponding elements in `df`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:4,
  Name = LETTERS[1:4],
  Country = "Nor",
  stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:4,
  Name = c("A", NA, NA, NA),
  Country = c(NA, "Bel", "Bel", "Bel"),
  stringsAsFactors = F)

df2[is.na(df2)] <- df[is.na(df2)]
df2
#>   ID Name Country
#> 1  1    A     Nor
#> 2  2    B     Bel
#> 3  3    C     Bel
#> 4  4    D     Bel
```

Comment: Thank you Paul! This is a very good solution but as it was mentioned below it works only when the tables have the same size and same column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)
d1 %>% 
  left_join(d2, by="ID") %>% 
  mutate(Country=case_when(
    is.na(Country.y) ~ as.character(Country.x),
    is.na(Name.y) ~ as.character(Country.y)
  )) %>% 
  select(ID, Name=Name.x, Country)
  ID Name Country
1  1    A     Nor
2  2    B     Bel
3  3    C     Bel
4  4    D     Bel
```

The `case_when` part is easily and freely expandable.

Data

```
d1 <- read.table(text="ID Name Country
1  A    Nor
2  B    Nor
3  C    Nor
4  D    Nor", header=T)
d2 <- read.table(text="ID Name Country
1  A    NA
2 NA    Bel
3 NA    Bel
4 NA    Bel", header=T)
```

Comment: Nice but dplyr is enough for that, no need for tidyverse per say. left_join, mutate pipe select etc.. are all part of dyplr.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the order is strictly the same and that df1 and df2 have the same size and that df1 has all the names defined (if not you need to go through a left_join). And well it is not base R but dplyr is a must have ;)

```
df3 <- dplyr::mutate(df1, Country = ifelse(is.na(df2$Country), Country, df2$Country))
```

Basically taking df1 as baseline (so as to keep the Names column, and replacing the column Country with the value for df2 unless there is NA.
(if you already have dplyr called then remove dplyr::).

with df1

```
ID Name Country
1  A    
2       Bel
3       Bel
4       Bel
```

and df2

```
ID Name Country
1  A    Nor
2  B    Nor
3  C    Nor
4  D    Nor
```

ps: I voted for @Paul for the base solution ... very neat.